# Using Drupal console, can I gitignore console folder?

Tags: version-control

I'm working on a Drupal 8 project, and installed [Drupal console](https://github.com/hechoendrupal/drupal-console) globally on my system.

The command `drupal init` created a `console` folder at the root of Drupal.

It seems to be used as a cache directory. Well it's a guess from what I see inside it.

Can I safely add this directory to my `.gitignore` file? Or should I commit it?

Comment: It depends on your need, if you don't want to track the changes in those files. Put it in gitignore else comit it

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but that doesn't really help me. The question is not do I need that directory or not. But does Drupal need it? In a deployment context.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add the console directory to your `.gitignore` like so:

```
/console
```

However, similar to drush, you may want to carry around project-specific configurations in your repository. This allows changing the behavior of Drupal Console on a per-repository basis.

If you do want to have per-repository Drupal Console configurations then do not gitignore the console directory and instead commit it to the project.

See https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/en/commands/init.html for details on how to initialize configurations.

Comment: While the init docs are sparse, I found https://github.com/hechoendrupal/drupal-console/issues/2725 which as some interesting information.